# Изменение условия, чтобы url был правильным

Tags: .htaccess, php

Подскажите, есть вот такое условие

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
} else {
    exit("1 !");
}
if (!preg_match("|^[\d]+$|", $id)) {
    exit("<p>bad URL</p>");
}
```

Оно работает при url вида profile?id=1, но не работает при url вида id1, хотя перепись в .htaccess есть, подскажите, что надо исправить, чтобы выражение стало правильное и для такого url вида id1.

Скрипт полностью

```
<?php
session_start();
include("bd.php");
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
} else {
    exit("1 !");
}
if (!preg_match("|^[\d]+$|", $id)) {
    exit("<p>bad url</p>");
}

if (!empty($_SESSION['email']) and !empty($_SESSION['password'])) {
    $email    = $_SESSION['email'];
    $password = $_SESSION['password'];
    $result2  = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE email='$email' AND password='$password'", $db);
    $myrow2   = mysql_fetch_array($result2);
    if (empty($myrow2['id'])) {
        exit("bad id!");
    }
} else {
    exit("3!");
}
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$id'", $db);
$myrow  = mysql_fetch_array($result);
if (empty($myrow['email'])) {
    exit("5");
}
?>
```

Comment: покажите "перепись", и результат print_r($_GET)

Comment: RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^id([0-9]+)$ profile?id=$1
а вот код страницы полностью,когда по ид страницы скрипт получает информацию о пользователе которому принадлежит страница(добавил к вопросу)

Comment: Выбрось курсы Попова!

Comment: а файл наверняка называется index.php и лежит в папке profile?

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста!В чем ошибка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я понял, то `$_GET['id']` должно содержать целое число.

`!preg_match("|^[\d]+$|", $id)` почему символы начала/конца данных стоят между символами условного выбора? Почему \d в символьном классе?

Нельзя вместо этой несуразной регулярки написать:

```
if(gettype($id) !== 'integer')
```

или

```
!preg_match("(\d{1,<тут макс. знач. id>)$", $id)
```

Comment: макс значения id нет тк оно auto_increment в mysql.$_GET['id'] - будет содержать число то есть ИД пользователя.все нормально определяется когда profile?id=1 но когда id1 выдает ошибку bad url.
Вот что написано в файле .htaccess RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^id([0-9]+)$ profile?id=$1,подскажите в чем ошибка ?

Comment: Вы можете сделать выборку по id, для этого используйте запрос типа: SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `users`.

В .htaccess попробуйте вместо profile?id=$1 написать profile?id$1

Comment: http://hashcode.ru/questions/122514/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-vk-com-id-ask-fm-username

Answer (score 1):

> ^id([0-9]+)$ profile?id=$1

т.е. вы ожидаете GET параметры прямо после доменного имени (типа [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com)?id1)? Может еще и страница какая-нибудь есть, тогда в ней дело?

PS действительно, вместо регулярного выражения тут было бы уместней использовать какую-нибудь встроенную функцию, которая будет работать быстрей и код читабельней будет, типа

```
if (is_numeric($id)) { ... }
```

Comment: Получается параметр вида profile?id= после id находиться ид пользователя по которому достается информация для страницы,но почему то это работает только с profile?id= но с другим это не работает,даже после реврайта,подскажите немного по подробнее как это можно реализовать по другому ?

Comment: То что должно получиться это понятно, мой комментарий был о изначальной строке url до изменения. У вас регулярное выражение начинается с ^ - т.е. с обозначения начала строки, следовательно подразумевается, что 'id....' это и будет началом URI строки и перед ней ничего не будет кроме доменного имени или того, что вы указали в .htaccess в RewriteBase. Очевидно, что rewrite не срабатывает, поэтому он не попадает под условие. Возможно я изначально неправильно изъяснил свою мысль, но после этого разъяснения попробуйте перечитать мой ответ еще раз возможно он стал понятней.